# iOS: Set profile picture to facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, profile-picture

I am working on one app in that i want to set profile picture of Facebook.
I am not getting any solution to set picture using sdk so it will be fine to have solution using graph API.

Comment: It is not possible to set user profile picture via API.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields":@"picture"}] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
    }];
}
```

After getting result, use the nsurlsession and get data, pass into the imageview[use main thread when using uielement].